# Deformed mesh after export

Tags: mesh, rigging, export, import, unreal-engine

So my issue is pretty frustrating. I am importing an FBX I have exported from Unreal Engine 4.19.2. It seems to import correctly or at least I think, you can see the bones below.

[image]

After exporting (I have tried all kinds of settings for this and cannot seem to figure out the issue). I import the mesh with skeleton back in Unreal Engine. All appears to be okie, no deformation. I now re-target an animation for this skeleton, like I have on the mesh before exporting to FBX. This time though it is a mess. You can see below.

[image]

Now to be 100% fully disclosed I did reshape this mesh from its original form, but I didn't touch the rig. I deleted half the body fixed what I needed and then mirrored it with a modifier (Not sure if that would be the issue or not).

Anyone know what the issue is or point me in the correct direction to solving this, I have been racking my brain trying multiple settings.

Unreal Engine 4.19.2 Export Settings

[image]

Blender 2.79 Export Settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppWra.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I noticed after looking to everything the skeleton bones are moving... i.e. lowerarm_r is now where upperarm_r is supposed to be and where lowerarm_r is supposed to be it is now hand_r... Anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: did you found a solution for that?

Comment: Negative. Tried many things to no avail.